# Currying n arguments create n functions

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have a function

```
//normal version
let addTwoParameters x y = 
   x + y
```

translate to curry version it looks like:

```
//explicitly curried version
let addTwoParameters x  =      // only one parameter!
   let subFunction y = 
      x + y                    // new function with one param
   subFunction                 // return the subfunction
```

What when I have a function with 4 arguments like:

```
let addTwoParameters a b c d = 
       a + b + c + d
```

How the currying version would be?

Comment: Your normal version is already curried one.
Currying is a transformation from tupled parameters to separate ones.

Comment: But how would be looks like after tranformation?

Comment: What @MaxMalook is saying is that [the compiler, behind the curtains, curries things for you](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/)

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis what you refer to is partial application.
Currying is only the transformation from `let f (a, b) = a + b` into `let f' a b = a + b`. Please consider reading this [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application)
Unfortunately Scott also made this mistake in his article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
let addTwoParameters a  =
    let subFunction1 b = 
        let subFuction2 c =
            let subFuction3 d =
                a + b + c + d
            subFuction3
        subFuction2
    subFunction1
```